# How to set a mock Date() with jest when I const it outside export default

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

here is my vue file

```
<script>
import dateFormat from 'dateformat';
const formatCurrentDate = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy/mm/dd');

export default {
  data() {
    currentDate: dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  },
},
</script>
```

and here is jest file

```
const systemDate = new Date('2022-06-23 13:29:00');

afterAll(() => {
  jest.useRealTimers();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  jest.setSystemTime(systemDate);
});
```

currentDate has changed to (2022-06-23) but formatCurrentDate still get current date value (2022/08/25).

I want formatCurrentDate will be change to (2022/06/23) like currentDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const formatCurrentDate` has been already evaluated during component, it cannot be affected without re-importing the component.

It's a mistake to put it outside the component, this makes it less testable. The way this is done is also determined by how up-to-date current date should be, but generally it is:

```
export default {
  data() {
    const formatCurrentDate = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy/mm/dd');

    currentDate: dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  },
```

Then it can be mocked before component instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's done. But I often see people declaring it outside the component rather than inside. If not writing UT, which way is better.

Comment: Totally depends on what behaviour you expect. It's the same date for all component instances when defined outside and won't be updated until the app is refreshed. Probably none of the above, and needs to be updated through a watcher constantly if you need it to be CURRENT date.